# Moving uploaded files to the logined user folder

Tags: php

Hello so here is the problem i have a login/register system and when the user creates his account a new folder gets created with same name as he puts username so if the username is test123 a folder test123 gets created. Now the problem is i dont know how to move files that user uploads with the upload system to his directory. And ofc user has to be loged in after he register to even upload files.

here is upload.php

```
<?php
if($_POST[submit]) {
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'];

    if($size <= 5000000){

        move_uploaded_file($temp,"userfiles/$name");
        echo "File: $name was uploaded!";

    } else{
        echo "Wrong size!";
    }
} else {
    header("Location: mojprofil.php");
}
?>
```

so actualy at the `move_uploaded_file($temp, "userfiles/$name");` in the folder **userfiles** there is a folder for each user that registers

and here is the register.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';



if(input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 20,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6
            ),
            'password_again' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
            ),
                'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);


            try {
                $user_dir = Input::get('username');

                $user->create(array(
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));
                Session::flash('home', '<h3>Registracija uspešna!</h3>');
                mkdir(__DIR__.'/userfiles/'.$user_dir);
                Redirect::to('mojprofil.php');

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I've always used a full server path when setting an upload path to any given directory.

So instead of this:

```
move_uploaded_file($temp,"userfiles/$name");
```

Try this:
    ... $tmp_filename= $_FILES['yourFile]['tmp_name']

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename,'/your/full/server/path/userfiles/'.$name);
```

Also, if your user has to be logged in, I'm assuming you might track their user id or something unique in some sort of session variable.
If you are setting the directory name based off of a _FILES variable, I think you might run risk of getting folder names that don't match user id/ username.

It would be better, in my opinion, to grab the username from some sort of query first to ensure everything matches. For example:

```
$username = get_user($_SESSION['user_id');  // returns user data -> id, username etc...

move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename,'/your/full/server/path/userfiles/'.$username);
```

That would give you something like:

```
/public_html/foo/bar/userfiles/username/
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_user() in upload.php on line 11` thats what i get when i do like u said

Comment: Yeah, you will have to write that method. That's not a native function. Somehow you should look up what user is logged in/creating an account.
I would create the user account, verify the user is captured in the DB, then turn around and create the directory after that. That way you will be sure you are working with a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very, very* rough but something along these lines:

```
$user_data = array();
$user_data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
...
...
// Logic to clean data before insert into DB.

$user = create_user($user_data);  // Return username, id or something unique.
if ($user) { // This contains username or false
    // Create directory with returned username then upload file
   ...
   ...
   // Logic to prep the file for upload
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename,'/your/full/server/path/userfiles/'.$user);
}
```